# Monkeypatching a requests.get() function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am testing my code, so far so good. But now I have to test a function using requests.get() to make an API call. 
As far as I understand, I have to 'mock' this function in my test.

My function calls Google Maps API, and in my test I added the wanted output:

```
     result = 

            {
                    "candidates":[
                        {
                            "geometry":{
                                "location":{
                                "lat":-34.5453062,
                                "lng":-58.44977489999999
                                }
                                },
                             "name":"Stade Monumental Antonio Vespucio Liberti",
                             "place_id":"ChIJ340B5jq0vJURijD6W6dgfz0"
                        }
                                ]
             }

    return json.dumps(result)
```

This the function I am testing:

```
def get_lat_lng (self):
        self.input_api = '%20'.join(self.parsed_question)
        self.input_api = ' '.join(self.parsed_question)
        self.google_api_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input={}&inputtype=textquery&fields=geometry,name,place_id&types=point_of_interest&key={}'.format (self.input_api, api_key)     
        self.r = requests.get (url = self.google_api_url)        
        self.data = self.r.json()                    
        self.name = self.data['candidates'][0]['name']       
        self.place_id = self.data['candidates'][0]['place_id']              
        self.lat = self.data['candidates'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']        
        self.lng = self.data['candidates'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']                
        return (self.lat, self.lng, self.place_id)
```

And my test so far:

```
def test_get_lat_lng (monkeypatch):    

    monkeypatch.setattr('requests.get', mock_get_lat_lng)
```

This is the error code I get when trying to run the test:

```
 self.r = requests.get (url = self.google_api_url)
>       self.data = self.r.json()
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I don't understand since I use json.dumps() on my desired output to "mock" an answer from requests.get(), how can it be a 'str' object? Looking for the type of `self.r` I get `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`.

Comment: can you post your code for initializing `mock_get_lat_lng`

Comment: Shouldn't that read `monkypatch(requests, 'get', mock_get_lat_lng)`?

Comment: my  `mock_get_lat_lng` starts like that: `def mock_get_lat_lng (url):`

Comment: I assumed that your first listing represents `mock_get_lat_lng`. Is that correct, and if yes, can you please edit the question to show this, e.g. add the function definition?

Comment: post the _whole_ function definition for `mock_get_lat_long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making mock_get_lat_lng() a class did the trick. Here is my final working test:

```
class mock_get_lat_lng():

    def __init__(self, url):
        pass

    def json(self):
        result = {
                "candidates": [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                            "location": {
                                "lat": -34.5453062,
                                "lng": -58.44977489
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "Stade Monumental Antonio Vespucio Liberti",
                        "place_id": "ChIJ340B5jq0vJURijD6W6dgfz0"
                    }
                ]
                }
        return result
```